# alert($(obj).attr("id")) worked; but $(obj).attr('id') undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to link to a pop-up window,

when I tested with `getId = alert($(obj).attr("id"))`, it shown the id value;

but when I change it to `getId = $(obj).attr('id')`, the value became `undefined`.

Any solution for this?

```js
// Pop-up window
var windowObject;
var getId;
openPopup(this.id);

function openPopup(obj) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all').click(function() {
      getId = $(obj).attr('id');
      //getId = alert($(obj).attr("id"));
    });
  });
  windowObject = window.open("slideshow/" + getId + ".html", "popup", width = 800, height = 500 ");
  }
```

Comment: You call `openPopup(this.id);` then you basically do `$(this.id).attr('id')`

Comment: @adeneo But of course! Don't forget to then do `$("#"+$(this).attr("id")).first()[0].id` to really make sure you get the ID of the thing!

Answer (score 1):

Your `getId` variable is defined only inside your click handler function. That's why alert inside this function works fine (as well as `getId = $(obj).attr('id');`), but gets undefined in the last string of code (which is outside of click callback). To fix it move the last string inside click handler function:

```
       function openPopup(obj) {
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.all').click(function() {
               getId = $(obj).attr('id');
               //getId = alert($(obj).attr("id"));
               windowObject = window.open("slideshow/" + getId + ".html", "popup", "width=800,height=500");
           });
       });

   }
```

Comment: Working like magic, thanks! But still don't understand... didn't I made getId a global variable?
Thanks a lot

Comment: It's global indeed, but it gets value only after the click event (and you tried to open window before click event). So until you've clicked on `.all` the `getId` variable won't be defined.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is it doesn't matter you've placed click handler before the `window.open`. The code inside this handler won't be executed until you click, but the last string is executed right when document is ready.

Comment: Thank you Natalia!